# Why does React JSX not support HTML5 entity names?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, html-entities, html4

As shown in this code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv3vv0mrmw), and noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035771/why-does-react-only-allow-a-subset-of-html-entities/46039149#46039149), only [HTML4 character entities](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/guide/entities.html) are supported within literal text in [JSX](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html).

Why are [HTML5 entity names](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) not supported? Specifying the names of any of the new HTML5 character entities within literal text in JSX like this

```
<div>&num;</div>
```

does not work.

Comment: React only accepts HTML4 entities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035771/why-does-react-only-allow-a-subset-of-html-entities

Comment: Why does it not support HTML5 entities? The documentation (https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)  makes no mention of which HTML version is supported.